# Can I glue cement backer board to Roth radiant floor panels instead of screwing them?

Tags: tile, heating

We are adding radiant floor heat to a concrete floor with Roth panels. Their info sheet shows concrete backer board attached with screws at 8" o.c. This would be hundreds of long Tapcons into the concrete. We would prefer to glue the backer onto the Roth panels. Top of panels is aluminum. What kind of long term results are we likely to get? Slab is very stable.

Comment: Can you glue them instead of gluing them? Don’t know? Do you know what glue?

Comment: Also, a link to the instruction manual for the panels you're using may help.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to tell you about the long term results unless they blatantly chose not to follow the instructions provided by the manufacturers.

Comment: Usually, concrete backer board is to protect wood from a possibly wet situation. Since you're not installing your "Roth panels" (whatever they are) over wood, you might not need the backer board at all. While you're asking the mfgr about the possibility of gluing down the backer board as [Ecnerwal suggests](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/250085/34147), ask them if it's even necessary when installing over concrete. If they have an approved solution for skipping the backer or gluing it down, you're golden. If not, ask them for suggestions.

Comment: It might be good with very specific questions like this one to include some links. This gives answerers some idea of how much research you've done, as well as give them a starting point for helping you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want.

If there's ever a problem, only the method following the manufacturer's instructions will be covered by any warranty applicable to the product.

Even if the failure appears to be for some totally unrelated reason that should be covered, not installing per instructions is going to shift the burden of proof onto you, so any "victory" will be pyrrhic (as well as unlikely.)

If your code enforcement people are picky, you might also fail an inspection for not following the manufacturer's instructions.

So, do whatever you like, eyes wide open and aware of who foots the bill if it doesn't work out like you hoped.

**Alternatively**, contact the manufacturer and inquire if there's an approved installation method similar to what you hope to do.